# Show that for a certain unrectifiable curve, the Riemann sums fail to converge although the integrand is smooth

Tags: complex-analysis

I have this problem:
[image: page1]

The hint being referred to is the curve, $\gamma(t) = t+ itsin(1/t)$.
If I modify the curve to be $\gamma(t) =t+it sin (1/t^2)$ and take the interval to be $\delta = t_j-t_{j-1}$,I need the Riemann sums $\sum_{j=1}^n \gamma(t^*) (\gamma(t_j)-\gamma(t_{j-1})$ to diverge. If I take $t^*=\frac{\delta}{2}$ I have to show that $|\sum_{j=1}^n (\frac{\delta}{2} + i sin (\frac{4}{\delta^2})(\gamma(t_j)-\gamma(t_{j-1})| \to \infty$.
Can you please help me to proceed?

Comment: It suffices to show that, given two different signed partitions, their difference does not go to $0$ as the mesh size tends to $0$.

Comment: Thankyou @Caffeine. Can I please get a more detailed explanation. Also, I have a more fundamental question, should'nt the Riemann sums be specified as $\gamma(t^*)(t_{j-1} - t_j)$? Instead we haved it specifiedas $\gamma(t^*) \gamma(t_{j-1})-\gamma(t_j)$.